# JQuery Chosen Multiselect plugin Scroll issue

Tags: jquery

I'm using the CHosen JQuery plugin. I get a scroll bar when I open the dropdown as there are many options. When I scroll to the middle of the options... the scroll bar moves to the end of the list making me unable to select the middle options. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known issue listed in bug list on choosen git hub. This is incompatibility with newer versions of jQuery. I have same problem in my project and it is fixed after I revert version of jQuery from 2.20 to 1.11.